# Pdf generator in lwc Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I want to generate  PDF  through LWC button following this tutorial"https://github.com/Coding-With-The-Force/Salesforce-Development-Tutorials/tree/main/lwc_pdf_generation".
Below is the code

pdfTest.js

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import {loadScript} from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import JSPDF from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jspdf';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/PdfGenerator.getContactsController';

export default class JspdfDemo extends LightningElement {
    contactList = [];
    headers = this.createHeaders([
        "Id",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName"
    ]);

    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, JSPDF)
        ]);
    }

    generatePdf(){
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
        const doc = new jsPDF({

        });

        doc.text("Hi I'm Matt", 20, 20);
        doc.table(30, 30, this.contactList, this.headers, { autosize:true });
        doc.save("demo.pdf");
        console.log("pdf is " +doc.save("demo.pdf"));
    }

    generateData(){
        
        getContacts().then(result=>{
            this.contactList = result;
            this.generatePdf();
        });
    }

    createHeaders(keys) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i ++) {
            result.push({
                id: keys[i],
                name: keys[i],
                prompt: keys[i],
                width: 65,
                align: "center",
                padding: 0
            });
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

pdfTest.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-button onclick={generateData} label="Generate PDF"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

PdfGenerator.cls

```
public with sharing class PdfGenerator
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContactsController(){
        return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact];
        
    }
}
```

but it shows me error "This page has an error.
**You might just need to refresh it.
[Cannot read property '0' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:pdfTest}"**

Comment: can you add your HTML here and what are you using to show PDF on HTML? jspdf or pdf.js?  keep in mind both of those are different libraries. I have recently worked on a showing pdf and I can help you if you add some more information to your code.

Comment: i using library jspdf.js . i already show HTML code above "pdfTest.html" . thats it .  only wo line code . what you need more?

Comment: @fado Did you resolve this, could you please post how you fixed it

Comment: No i am still stuck